# Utilisation de il, elle et lui pour des objets inanimés

Tags: pronoms

Est-il correct d’utiliser ces pronoms personnels pour des objets inanimés ? Il me semble que ces pronoms sont avant tout réservés à des objets animés, et peut-être à des personifications.

- Je n’utiliserais personnellement pas “lui”, **lui** préférant « celui-ci » ou « celle-là ».
- “Il” est plus complexe, **il** est difficile de s’en passer. Par exemple, la phrase suivante est-**elle** correcte?

  > J’ai trouvé mon ordinateur ; il était sur le bureau.
- “elle” est plus complexe, revêtant simultanément le rôle de “il” et “lui”. Les mêmes questions s'y appliquent.

J’ai utilisés les pronoms dans les phrases ci-dessus, ces utilisations sont-elles correctes ?

Je souhaiterais me faire indiquer des ressources sur les règles grammaticales s'appliquant à ces pronoms.

Comment: J'ai trouvé ce site, je n'ai pas tout lu mais il a l'air assez complet
http://www.patenotte.name/Aix/Ecriture/Feuilles_aides_pedagogiques/pronomsobjets.htm
Sinon oui ton exemple est correcte. Comme en français les objets sont genré tu utilises il ou elle en fonction du genre.

Comment: Tu fais bien ce que tu veux avec les pronoms. Parfois... au lieu de *lui*... je dis *l'autre*... alors... ;-) Blague à part... il est aussi amusant que curieux de te lire préférer *celle-là* à *lui*. *Lui* est issu du latin *illi* datif de *illa* (*celle-là*) comme quoi... ça veut dire... la même chose!

Comment: C'est tout à faire correct. Se référer aux pages wikipédia par exemple, ou autre, sur l'usage anaphorique des pronoms en français. "“elle” est plus complexe, revêtant simultanément le rôle de “il” et “lui”. Les mêmes questions s'y appliquent." En quoi? Il nous faut des références, parce que c'est assez inédit.

Answer (score 2):

Il est tout à fait correct d'utiliser les pronoms « il(s) » et « elle(s) » avec des objets inanimés.

> Le bureau est petit mais **il** a beaucoup de tiroirs.
> La machine s'est arrêtée; **elle** est encore en panne.

La phrase est correcte.

Il y a cependant des difficultés pour l'utilisation de  « lui ».

Que le nom de l'objet inanimé soit masculin ou féminin, dans un langage pas très soigneux le pronom peut être « lui »  pour le COI, mais le [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/lui/48033) recommande l'usaage de « en » lorsque la préposition est « de » (de lui, d'elle) et « y » lorsqu'elle est « à » (à lui, à elle).

On peut donc entendre des phrases comme les deux suivantes.

> Le bureau est sale, je vais **lui** mettre un coup d'éponge.
> La table est mouillée, je vais **lui** mettre un coup de torchon.

Mais il est vraiment correct de s'en tenir à l'usage que montre les phrases suivantes (Larousse).

> - Cet endroit vous rappelle trop de souvenirs, il vaudrait mieux vous **en** éloigner (et non : *vous éloigner de lui)
> - Ce sont mes vacances, et je veux **en** profiter (et non : *profiter d'elles)
> - Cette question est importante, fais-y bien attention (et non : *fais bien attention à elle)

**Sur lui/sur elle, sous lui/sous elle, dans lui/dans elle**

Pour les inanimés, ces locutions prépositives ne sont pas utilisées ; à la place de chaque paire, on utilise respectivement « **dessus, dessous, dedans** » ([Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/lui/48033)).

> (Larousse)
> ♦ Voilà le hangar, vous pouvez mettre votre voiture dessous (et non : *sous lui)
> ♦ je te donnerai une belle boîte, tu rangeras tes lettres dedans (et non : *dans elle)

En ce qui concerne les autres prépositions il n'y a pas de changement.

> (Larousse)
> ♦ l'incendie n'a rien laissé derrière lui
> ♦ le tracteur roulait au pas et après lui venait un camion ;

Le cas d'utilisation de « celui-ci » n'est pas précisé mais il doit s'agir du cas du pronom sujet; la supposition faite est correcte ; « celui-ci » est un pronom utilisable pour un COD, COI et pour un sujet;  « lui » ne s'utilise que pour les COI, « le » et « la » pour les COD.

> Ces bureaux sont grands; **celui-ci** est en bois vernis et elle le préfère.
> Ce bureau est bien beau mais trop cher pour moi; je vais acheter **celui-ci** (*ou* celui-là).

**ADDITION**

Il existe un point délicat en rapport avec l'utilisation de « lui »; prêtons d'abord attention à quelques précisions à propos d'un mode d'utilisation très particulier de « lui » (« lui » n'étant pas le seul pronom consacré à cet usage et la discussion s'appliquant donc à certains autres pronoms); selon [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronom) ce pronom est utilisé en tant que « **forme disjointe** » et cela de deux façons.

- *en position détachée*; ex : Lui, il l'a échappée belle, la foudre a tué tous les autres.
- *en tant que sujet mis en relief*; ex : Lui reste satisfait, il ne se plaint jamais.

La question épineuse concerne l'utilisation du pronom dans le mode qui vient d'être exposé selon ce que représente le nom, soit être inanimé soit être animé.

La question ne se pose pas lorsque l'être animé est un mâle de l'espèce humaine, « lui » ne peut pas introduire une discordance. Elle commence à se poser lorsque l'être animé est un animal. Il semble que déjà l'utilisation de lui n'ait plus autant la faveur du locuteur et que « lui » soit plutôt utilisé lorsque l'animal est un animal domestique cher ou un animal qui acquiert passagèrement un statut similaire dans l'esprit du locuteur. Lorsque l'être est inanimé il semble que presque toujours soit préférable au locuteur de recourir à une autre méthode pour communiquer une idée de mise en valeur telle que communiquée par l'utilisation de la forme disjointe; cette autre méthode serait souvent celle d'utiliser un démonstratif, lequel a un effet similaire en cela qu'il distingue d'un tout un ou plusieurs éléments. En conclusion le pronom « lui » dans cet emploi en tant que forme disjointe est marqué. Qu'il soit souhaitable ou non de lui préserver ce statut,  de mon seul point de vue, reste indécidable.

Deux exemples test

> Tous ces tableaux ne me plaisent pas beaucoup; il y a quand même ce groupe de trois par ici; regardes les deux premiers d'abord, pas le dernier; lui, il n'est pas aussi récent!

*« celui-là n'est pas pas aussi récent! »* ne semblerait-elle pas une phrase plus usuelle?

> Il y a tous ces livres et puis cette autre pile là-bas; eux, ils ne les ouvrent jamais.

Ne préfère-t-on pas dire « *ils n'ouvrent jamais ceux-là.* »?

Comment: Celui-là/-ci utilisé comme pronom anaphore, c'est uniquement dans du langage littéraire très recherché. Les deux phrases à la fin de la réponse sont bien naturelles que les modifications proposées

Comment: @Eau Je ne saisis pas votre remarque; indépendamment, je suis très surpris en ce qui concerne « celui-ci/celui-là », je les utilise couramment dans la langue parlée.

Comment: .j'essayais une forme un peu désuètes pour la circonstance, merci de votre réponse.